# Use where condition with array in postgresql doesn't work

Tags: arrays, postgresql

I'm trying to use an array that was declared earlier in a postgres script, but I keep getting the following error :

```
op ANY/ALL (array) requires array on right side
```

This is my code :

```
DO $$ 
DECLARE
   id_cie VARCHAR(50) := ARRAY(select id from main_cies);
BEGIN
   RAISE NOTICE '%%%', id_cie;
   drop table if exists network;
   create table network as
   select
       req_real_estate_qc_shareholders.id as id,
       req_real_estate_qc_shareholders.name as name,
       'Main owners' as relation,
       req_real_estate_qc_shareholders.address_num as num,
       req_real_estate_qc_shareholders.street_name as street,
       req_real_estate_qc_shareholders.suite as suite,
       req_real_estate_qc_shareholders.zip as zip
   from req_real_estate_qc_shareholders 
   where req_real_estate_qc_shareholders.id = ANY(id_cie);
END $$;
```

I don't understand the error since when I print the value I get the following array :

```
{1173569659,1173569659}
```

Comment: I provided an answer below for this particular case, though I wonder why you do the `ANY()` at all. Why not just join to the `main_cies` table in the `...as select ...` portion of the `CREATE TABLE`?

Comment: You don't use an array: id_cie VARCHAR(50). Why don't use a simple JOIN to get the same result, but simpler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:
`id_cie VARCHAR(50) := ARRAY(select id from main_cies);`
is converting the ARRAY into a string(`'{1173569659,1173569659}'`).

As in:

```
select pg_typeof(array[1,2]::varchar);
     pg_typeof     
-------------------
 character varying
```

You are looking for `VARCHAR[]`:

```
select pg_typeof(array[1,2]::varchar[]);
      pg_typeof      
---------------------
 character varying[]
```

So:

`id_cie VARCHAR[] := ARRAY(select id from main_cies);`

Though if the `id`s are actually integers I would choose:

`id_cie INTEGER[] := ARRAY(select id from main_cies);`

Answer (score 1):

You could write the same functionality without the usage of a variable. This avoids the issue that the declaration of the variable is wrong: it's not an array.

This could work:

```
DO
$$
    BEGIN
        DROP TABLE IF EXISTS network;
        CREATE TABLE network AS
        SELECT req_real_estate_qc_shareholders.id          AS id
             , req_real_estate_qc_shareholders.name        AS name
             , 'Main owners'                               AS relation
             , req_real_estate_qc_shareholders.address_num AS num
             , req_real_estate_qc_shareholders.street_name AS street
             , req_real_estate_qc_shareholders.suite       AS suite
             , req_real_estate_qc_shareholders.zip         AS zip
        FROM req_real_estate_qc_shareholders
                 JOIN main_cies ON req_real_estate_qc_shareholders.id = main_cies.id;
    END
$$;
```